# How to retrieve a list of Columns from a single row in Cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

The below is a sample of my Cassandra CF.

```
     column1          column2          column3             ......
```

row1 : **name**:abay,**value**:10  **name**:benny,**value**:7  **name**:catherine,**value**:24 ................

ComparatorType:utf8

How can i fetch columns with name ('abay', 'john', 'peter', 'allen') from this row in a single query using Hector API.
The number of names in the list may vary every time.
I know that i can get them in a sorted order using SliceQuery.
But there are cases when i need to fetch data randomnly, as i mentioned above.
Kindly help me.

Comment: I suspect your data model is wrong for your queries, but it's unclear from what you've shared.  What is your key?  How many columns are stored in a typical row?  Is this the only query you need to perform on the data, or are there others?

Comment: Actually, my normal query would be a sorted one, that can be done using SliceQuery.setRange(). But at certain cases, i need to fetch a random list of columns from this row. Does querying a random set of columns from a row degrades performance? I am using levelled compaction for this cf.

Comment: How many columns do you typically have in a row?

Comment: Few hundreds to few thousands.
And, this CF will have a few lakh rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, it seems you have two options.

1. If you only need to run this query occasionally, you can get all columns for the row and filter them on the client.  If you have at most a few thousand columns, this should be ok for an occasional query.
2. If you need to run this frequently, you'll want to write the data such that you can query using name as the key.  This probably means you'll have to write the data twice into two CFs, where one is by your current key, and the other is by name.  This is a common Cassandra tactic.

Comment: Well, I already have name as column comparator. I'm using slicequery.setColumnNames(name1, name 2, ....) to read from this row. Will it perform well? Thanks a lot for taking time to answer my question :)

Comment: Problem is you'll do a lot of seeking, and you can't parallelize it.  If each name has a key, you can run parallel gets directly against the key.